# bower or grunt keeps removing jquery from index.html

Tags: jquery, gruntjs, bower

This is driving me crazy. So far Bower+Grunt (via Yeoman) has been a major source of frustration and a waste of time. All I want is my app to use the latest (2.1.0) version of jquery.

`bower list` correctly reported jquery 2.1.0 as an official update.

I ran `bower install --save jquery` to update to the last version, which it did.

The `bower list` command now correctly reports `jquery#2.1.0` as a dependency, and
the `bower.json` file now correctly lists jquery with the wanted version as a dependency:

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "angular": "1.2.13",
    "jquery": "~2.1.0",
    "sizzle": "1.10.16",
    "bootstrap": "~3.0.3",
    ...
```

But every time I run `grunt build` or `grunt serve` the `<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>` list gets removed from `index.html`, preventing the entire app from functioning.

```
#> grunt serve
Running "serve" task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task
Cleaning .tmp...OK

Running "bower-install:app" (bower-install) task

jquery was not injected in your file.
Please go take a look in "app/bower_components/jquery" for the file you need, then manually include it in your file.

Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task
...
```

Adding it manually doesn't solve anything. I'm completely stuck. There must be something I am doing wrong but I've been banging my head for a long time while being completely unproductive. Thank you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's a long answer here, but I only have time for a short one, and I figured I might as well give that instead of nothing!

`bower-install` is a task that depends on Bower packages properly specifying a `main` property inside of their `bower.json`. Some recent stuff has gone on with the jQuery Bower package, and it no longer specifies this property. Without, `grunt-bower-install` can't help much.

The solution is to manually include that reference to jQuery outside of the `<!-- bower:js --><!-- endbower -->` block in your HTML.

Sorry for the frustration. Hopefully, jQuery will fix its bower.json soon.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! In my investigation I did come to trying to add the missing main section in JQuery's bower.json, to no avail. My current "solution" (because I'd like to keep my job), is to move the script include outside of the bower controlled block in the HTML, as you correctly suggested.

Comment: Stephen, I just now realized that you are the author of grunt-bower-install. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Ugh, having this problem with ACE editor (ace-builds doesn't have bower.json and gets removed from index.html ... while angular-ui-ace is just fine).  Don't like workaround, but I guess it's the best for now :-/

Comment: Using this solution may cause issues in `grunt` build though.

Comment: Has this been known to happen with other libraries as well?  I did a bower install --save ui-router and it too gets stripped out of my index.html every time I run grunt serve even though it looks right in bower.json For right now I've just placed the reference elsewhere but this buggy behaviour really erodes the utility of using bower

Answer (score 16):

There's an even better solution here that doesn't force you to move the script tag away from the other bower components.  You can use an `overrides` section (found on https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/issues/20)

Add the following section to your project's `bower.json`

```
...
"overrides": {
    "jquery": {
        "main": "dist/jquery.js"
    }
}
```

Comment: It did not help me in case of ngcordova - I have bower.json: {
 ..
  "overrides": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "main": [
        "less/bootstrap.less",
        "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ]
    },
    "ngCordova": {
      "main": [
        "dist/js/ng-cordova.js"
      ]
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

I saw the same problem a few minutes ago with grunt + yeoman + bower. In my case, the "overrides" solution did not work.

```
grunt wiredep
```

kept reordering the entries in app/index.html. The problem turned out to be the location of jquery in the dependencies section of bower.json. In my case, jquery was the 9th entry in the dependencies section in bower.json.

```
grunt wiredep
```

would then move

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
```

to location #9 in app/index.html even if I manually made it #1 entry or used overrides.

In my case, jquery needs to be ahead of angular and this reordering was killing my app at runtime.

My dependencies section in bower.json looked like this **before**:

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.4.8",
    "angular-animate": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-aria": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-cookies": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-messages": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-resource": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-route": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.3.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.3",
},
```

Now, it looks like this (notice how jquery has relocated to position #1).

```
"dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^2.2.3",
    "angular": "1.4.8",
    "angular-animate": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-aria": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-cookies": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-messages": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-resource": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-route": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.3.0",
}
```

I am putting this here so that others could use this solution, if nothing else works.

Comment: What version of grunt are you using? The same happens to me with grunt 3.10.5, but 3.10.3 seems to not have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The simple and proper solution is to add this reference under overrides section in bower.json: like here I added for jquery-ui.

```
"overrides": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "main": [
        "less/bootstrap.less",
        "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ]
    },
    "jquery-ui": {
      "main": [
        "themes/base/jquery-ui.css",
        "ui/jquery-ui.js"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Cheers :)