# Yeoman Angular.js/Express.js - Grunt overwrites index.html on each manual restart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am new at using Yeoman and I am using it for bootstraping a Angular.js and Express.js. The Gruntfile.js seems overwhelming. I have a couple of issues:

1. Everytime I restrart the webserver with 'grunt start' my
   app/index.html file gets overwritten. This is a nightmare...how can
   I stop this?
2. I add a normal css directory... app/css. How can I
       get grunt to detect file changes in it and reload the browser? I
       tried `'css/*.css'` but no luck:

   ```
   watch: {
       files: [
         '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
         'css/*.css',
         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
         '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
       ]   
     }'
   ```

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to fix the index.html file being overwritten? I'm experiencing the same thing and attempting to fix it.

Comment: Fixed. Not sure if this is the case for you but for me I was adding my javascript and css includes inside of the bower section (commented with bower:js) within index.html. As per @morloch, inside the grunt.js file 'serve' task function was a call to bowerInstall. The bowerInstall replaces everything inside these comments with bower includes. Once I moved my includes outside of this they were left alone. I pulled this answer in [this post from @stephen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21862757/bower-or-grunt-keeps-removing-jquery-from-index-html)

Answer (score 1):

Grunt is running in the root folder of your application tree, so although you were on the right track modifying the watch object, you will need to add `<%= yeoman.app %>/` before your `css/*.css` so it will look in the correct folder. `yeoman.app` is actually just a variable located towards the top of the file.

To test your app, use `grunt serve` and that shouldn't overwrite your index file.  Otherwise, find the section in your `Gruntfile.js` where `grunt.registerTask('serve'` is defined, locate the `grunt.task.run` and try commenting out each task and re-running `grunt serve` to find the culprit that is overwriting your index file.