# Test an Angular directive that uses jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I am having trouble writing unit tests for some of my Angular directives. Particularly, those that use jQuery inside the directive.  I have contrived an minimal example below that illustrates my issue.

This silly directive binds the click event to the element. When clicked, it hides the element. [According to Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element), elements passed into directives will be wrapped as jQuery elements.  if jQuery is available it will use jQuery, otherwise it will use Angular's jQuery Lite.  Indeed, if I use this directive in a browser with jQuery included, the directive works and will hide the clicked element.

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('clickhide', function() { return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) { 
        element.bind('click', function(e) {
            element.hide();
            scope.$digest();
        });
    }
}});
```

Here is the Karma unit test spec for this directive:

```
describe('clickhide', function() {
    var scope, elm;

    beforeEach(module('MyApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
        scope = $rootScope;
        elm = angular.element('<div clickhide></div>');
        $compile(elm)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
    }));

    it('should do a click', function() {
        elm[0].click();
        //OOPS: undefined is not a function error
        expect($(elm).find(":hidden").length).toBe(1);
    });
});
```

When I run this test, it fails with an error of "undefined is not a function" meaning that jQuery was not loaded and Angular used jQuery Lite instead, which doesn't define hide().

I have found two ways to work around this.

1. Don't use jQuery. Requires rewriting my directives which I don't want to do.
2. Explicitly wrap elements in my directives to make them jQuery elements: `$(element).hide()`.  Also requires modifications to my directives, which I would prefer not to do. If there is no alternative, I can certainly do this.

I feel like it should be possible to get Angular to automatically use jQuery inside a directive when unit testing like it does when using in a web browser.  I believe the key point is this line from Angular's documentation:

> To use jQuery, simply load it before DOMContentLoaded event fired.

Its not clear to me when DOMContentLoaded happens when running unit tests. My Karma config file includes jQuery as the first file, before angular:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '../../',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'ng-scenario'],
    files: [
      'app/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      ...
    ],
    exclude: [],
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    runnerPort: 9100,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    captureTimeout: 60000,
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Do I need to inject jQuery into the test?  Maybe this is a limitation of Karma?  Anyone know?

Comment: Could you try `expect(elm.find(":hidden").length).toBe(1);`?

Comment: It doesn't even get to that line because it has an error on the line above because of the thing I described.

Comment: oh ok. How have you tried to load jQuery in your app?

Comment: In my karma config file, I load jQuery as the first file in the "files" section and jQuery works. It loads. But for some reason angular still uses jQuery Lite as the default element wrapper.

Comment: In karma OK, but in your APP ? :)

Comment: In the app, jQuery is loaded in the index.html file, but as you know Karma doesn't care about the html files. My app works fine. Its Karma that is having the trouble.

Comment: Could you add your karma config file in your question?

Comment: Are you sure wrapping element in $() works? Might it be possible jQuery is not loaded at all? Could you please check if the bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js exists?

Comment: possible duplicate of [bower or grunt keeps removing jquery from index.html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21862757/bower-or-grunt-keeps-removing-jquery-from-index-html)

Comment: Do you really need jQuery just for the hide function?

Comment: hide() was just a minimal example. In practice I am doing more complicated stuff, but the root problem is easier to understand if I make a simple example.

Comment: @Jake have you found a working solution for this without wrapping all elements with jQuery?

Comment: Not yet. I would like to but haven't tried too hard to figure it out.  In the meantime, I use integration testing (Protractor) to cover my directives.

Answer (score 2):

Try to override $ in beforeEach block of the test.

```
beforeEach(function() {
  $.fn.hide = function() {
    this.css( "display", "none" )
  };
});
```

Comment: I have jquery loaded in my karma conf file at the top, but am getting $ undefined.  Do we need to do anything further to access the $ for jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve similar issue by loading jquery before angular.
Also if $ is failing for you, You can always use angular.element('') in place of $